# Using php library in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I installed using composer the following library: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

Unfortunetly, there are no documentations about how to add it to include and use it on my Laravel project.

How I can `use` this class? Currently I get this:

> message":"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Firebase' not found"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently in a namespace, which mean if nothing is specified it'll look in:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Specify to import your library in the namespace:

```
use Firebase;
```

It will load the class in the controller.