# What is the proper way to get ready a 3rd party package in Laravel 5 (5.4)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to migrate an existing project from laravel 4 to laravel 5.

For that I installed a fresh laravel project and import code in it.

I installed a required package in laravel 5:

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```

When I call Agent class to use, laravel gives following error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Agent' not found
```

What is "use ..." line to add at the top of controller? Or any other solutions?

Not: `use Agent;` results in `Class 'Agent' not found` error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using php library in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032136/using-php-library-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Agent` is a facade, you should use full namespace:

```
$agent = \Agent::....;
```

Or add `use` clause to the top of your controller:

```
use Agent;
```

Comment: How can just "use Agent" line give shortcut? Is it in root directory?

Comment: `use Agent;` results in `Class 'Agent' not found` error.

Comment: @user2356198 did you install the package correctly including putting facade alias into the `app.php` config?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add facades in app/config/app.php
Laravel (optional)

Add the service provider in app/config/app.php:

```
'Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider',
```

And add the Agent alias to app/config/app.php:

```
'Agent' => 'Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent',
```

Source: **https://github.com/jenssegers/agent**